# How to change a textView in another axml that is not a Resource for this Activity.cs?

Tags: xamarin.android, c#-3.0

I know how to work with elements such as buttons, textViews in Activity-file when I have:

```
 SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Gesture1);
 FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.helloBn).Click += delegate
 {
    Toast.MakeText(this, "hello", ToastLength.Short).Show();
 };
```

It works well. But i need to change textView.text of another axml from here.
How can I do that?